# How do I continuously move my character in Pygame without moving the mouse

Tags: python, pygame

My character continuously moves when I hold down the arrow keys but only when I move the mouse. I did what the documentation said but How do I solve this problem?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

look = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

x =50
y = 50
width = 30
height = 30
move = 5

run = True
while run:
  pygame.time.delay(10)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - 30:
       x += move
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
       x -= move
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
        y -= move
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - 30:
        y += move

    look.fill((0,0,0))


    pygame.draw.rect(look, (255,0,0), (x,y, width, height))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: All lines from `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` to `pygame.display.flip()` need to be indented one level less